# Add space and three dots (ellipsis) between ggplot2 facets to indicate omitted facets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a `facet`ed `ggplot` where each facet is a day of the month. I want to replace days 4 through 29 with space and three dots (ellipsis) to remind my reader about the omitted days. I see that `theme()` allows customization, but I do not see any options that would allow me to insert space and three dots between day 3 and day 30 facets.

Should I resort to Photoshop or MS Paint?

```r
library(tidyverse)

tibble(day = rep(1:30, 5), value = runif(5*30)) %>% 
    filter(day %in% c(1:3, 30)) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = value)) +
    geom_histogram() +
    facet_grid(day ~ .)
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-11-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I think the only way to come close to doing this would require manually editing grobs within the `ggplot2` object. If you search for questions that include the `gridExtra` and `grid` packages, you'll see a layout and workflow that can mimic the learning-curve of some programming languages, and "robust" solutions can be rather tricky. While certainly not *impossible*, you might want to ask yourself how much work you want to put into it to get that to happen. (I might be mistaken.)

Comment: @r2evans Not _that_ much work. Thanks!

Comment: From your *"space and three dots"* I had inserted just space, not an empty pane. Glad you found something satisfactory!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an option making `day` a `factor`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

tibble(day = rep(1:30, 5), value = runif(5*30)) %>% 
  filter(day %in% c(1:3, 30)) %>% 
  mutate(day = factor(day, levels = c('1','2','3','...','30')))%>% #new
  ggplot(aes(x = value)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  facet_grid(day ~ ., drop = F) #added drop = F
```

[image: ggplot unused facet factor]